# js. hide dynamically created button by increasing ID onclick

Tags: javascript, button, hide

My goal is to make kind of a counting game. 
Starting by a click on button number 1, then 2, 3, etc.

I created those buttons in a for loop. Then I tried:

```
btn.onclick = function() {
  s = 0;
  while (s == this.id && s < 3) {
    this.style.display = "none";
    s++;
  }
};
```

It only works for the first button. I want my variable `s` to be `s = 2` on the second run.

Thanks!

Comment: Please add the relevant HTML so we can replicate your issue and show a working result. But, the short answer is declare `s` outside of your callback function because as you have it, a new `s` is created for each `click` event callback and that `s` is always reset to `0`.

Comment: Thank you, that helped a lot!